# TFS Release Error "Application type and version is still in use"

Tags: azure-service-fabric, ms-release-management

I am building and release a service fabric application that is giving me errors during a deploy.  The error is not consistent though.  I can deploy fine one time and the next I get this error:

Application type and version is still in use

If I deploy this service fabric app to the server directly from visual studio it will deploy every time without error.  So I am pretty sure the application is working and building without errors.  I only get this error when I use the TFS Release agent.  Does anyone know where I should be looking to fix this?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration) explains how to set up a CD pipeline. It also describes how to do in place upgrades, by deinstall/install.

Deinstalling and installing the same Application version will cause downtime. Usually it's better to do rolling upgrades. To do this, update the Application package manifest files during every build.

Install / uninstall using scripts is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications#remove-an-application).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect when you are deploying from VS you are killing the application and installing a new one, at least this is the default behavior. It's fine but results in downtimes.

When working with TFS there are two essential steps:

1. Update service fabric application version on build - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/service-fabric-versioning
2. Once packaged, upgrade application using another task - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/service-fabric-deploy

Comment: Down times are not a problem for the services.  Do you by chance know what the powershell scripts are to kill the application?  I may put that into my release definition prior to the deploy task to ensure this service gets copied.